# jenkins CPU growth up CPU - with jenkins.war process

Tags: jenkins, cpu-usage

I have jenkins running on vm, and all the time the CPU usage takes most of the CPU capacity, by jenkins.war process
tried to restart the jenkins, the CPU wend down but in 1-2 min growth again.
(I have like 20 jobs and I keep 5 builds foe each one)
any idea what could it be?

[the proccess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai9kW.jpg)

[the htop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw5Uz.png)

Comment: No one can read those screenshots; post text, plus more details. IE: job load.etc.

Comment: Please read [ask].